# How to load view commonly in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an application in code igniter.

How can i load a view commonly so that i don't need to load it individually for all the functions ?

Here is the code :

controller.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->load->view('css');   
        $this->load->view('js');
    }
public function about()
        {
            $this->load->view('about');
            $this->load->view('css');   
            $this->load->view('js');
        }
```

Here i can load the `$this->load->view('css');` and `$this->load->view('js');` into common file called `$this->load->view('comp');` and load it.

But what i want to know is i don't need to do it for each functions. How can i do it commonly ?

something like

```
class site extends CI_Controller 
{

  **  Here the view should be loaded  $this->load->view('comp');
public function index()
{
$this->load->view('about');.
}
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a function:- you can use it commonly write function in that file which included commonly

```
public function loading_views($view) {
  $this->load->view($view);
  $this->load->view('css');   
  $this->load->view('js');
}
```

and then your functions will be

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->loading_views('index');
    }
public function about()
    {
        $this->loading_views('about');
    }
```

Comment: Should the **function loading_views($view)** be public ?

Comment: Thanks. It was smart enough !!

Answer (score 1):

I use a method on a base controller called `showPage`:

```
MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  protected function showPage($template,$data) {
     $this->load->view('css');   
     $this->load->view('js');
     $this->load->view($template,$data);
  }
}
```

Then just in any controller call:
`$this->showPage('about',$data);`